# "Android SDK components needed" in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I downloaded `Bitwarden` mobile repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile).
When I open the solution with Visual Studio for Mac the following popup shows:

[image]

What this `popup` message mean. I don't want to use any `older SDK`. If required how to update the `Android Project` to use the latest SDK installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use Xamarin, but I guess it still reads [src/Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/blob/master/src/Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml), which shows `android:targetSdkVersion="26"` at [line 3](https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/blob/master/src/Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml#L3). Maybe modify this value to the corresponding value of your current SDK version will solve your issue.